# kde screenlock wont accept password and have to first press switch user

Tags: kubuntu, login, themes, lock-screen

I am on kubuntu jammy and I have run into a problem. when I lock screen with `meta`+`L` I can put in a password but clicking on the button or pressing enter wont work, it will show the animation of being pressed but wont actually accept the password, no password is wrong indication either.

the workaround I found is to first press switch user and then log back in, as I would on a fresh startup. that seems to work fine.

anyone know how to fix this?

I have seen this with multiple custom screen lock interfaces, one that comes to mind right now is the one set by the global theme [DesktopPal97](https://store.kde.org/p/1985239/)